# Easy way to present a much larger progress ring?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, progress-ring

The [lightning-progress-ring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-ring/example) component implements the [Progress Ring](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-ring/) SLDS styling, but both of those only offer medium and large sizes so no bigger than this:

[image: large size example progress ring]

i.e. these seem designed to go e.g. inline in tables more than to stand out as the major component in a screen.

Suggestions for how to output a much large one?

**PS**

The CSS scale transform kind of works but I don't understand why the positioning gets messed up and it looks. rather bare scaled up:

[image: scale 5 example]

FYI a [third party progress ring implementation](https://github.com/texei/progress-ring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we do not have much access to the internal styles of the SLDS CSS for this component.

I would improvise a bit on what you have already to make it easier to manage.

```
<template>
  <lightning-progress-ring value="75" class="progress-ring"> 
   </lightning-progress-ring>
</template>
```

The .css file is as below

```
.progress-ring {
    transform: scale(6) translate(1em,1em);
    position: absolute
}
```

You can see it in action [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/QXBQzWO1wYtQ2UOal3iX)

With position flagged to absolute, I can control the margins easily with the translate property. Also moved from `px` to `em` to keep spacing consistent when working with the media queries or for different device resolutions.

Comment: Doesn't the use of absolute positioning conflict with Salesforce security as it might potentially be used as part of a click jacking hack? Would this solution pass a security review?

Comment: Hi @PhilW, Have you seen a security review picking up absolute positioning as a problem?

Comment: Thanks Monith; your CSS understanding is way better than mine. But I think I will go the "roll your own" route given there are plenty of examples out there in Google land.

Comment: Hey @KeithC yes we have.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. Time to go searching for that in our LWCs... Does SF provide documentation on this subject?

Comment: In the past I have been able to document as false positive for all components that do not go into app builder! But well it’s better to roll your own to please security review!

Answer (score 1):

You could zoom in the element with CSS. Here's an example:

## CSS

```
.very-large {
    zoom: 1000%;
}
```

## Template

```
<template>
    <lightning-progress-ring class="slds-align_absolute-center very-large" value={percent}>
    </lightning-progress-ring>
</template>
```

## JS

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  percent = 0;
  connectedCallback() {
    setInterval(() => this.percent = (this.percent+1)%100,100);
  }
}
```

[See the output here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/4yg7Ib4z3UOSzTUCzjpj).

Note that the progress ring isn't designed for large scale use. You'd probably rather want to use `lightning-spinner` instead, but even those aren't going to be much larger without a zoom on them.

Comment: Zoom is not consistent feature! I don’t recommend as it won’t work well in many browsers! Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Ah, I see [now](https://caniuse.com/css-zoom). That's unfortunate. I suppose the only real choice left would be to "roll your own" then. I'd advise against using the ring anyways, it ring isn't meant for the purpose Keith is going for.

Comment: Nice demo! Yeah I'm now thinking "roll your own" is the way to go. A Google of "progress ring" bring up plenty of techniques.