# LWC progress ring : remove dot circle and value inside

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on `lightning-progress-ring`, When i see progress ring in local server it's showing perfect. but in Org, there is a small circle appearing.

Help required

1. I want to get rid of this small circle ( 2nd image)
2. i want to write some value inside ring. is this possible ? ( 3rd image)

For increasing the size i have follow this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/332197/49944

In Local Server ( i want like this )

[image]

In Org

[image]

Need to write

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own LWC component from the [Progress Ring](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-ring/) blueprint. The path declaration looks complex, but is actually pretty straightforward, with just a few parts that need customization.The breakdown of the progress ring's `d` attribute can be broken down like so:

```
d="M 1 0 A 1 1 0 {isLong} 1 {arcX} {arcY} L 0 0"
```

- isLong: a binary flag if the arc should 'take the long path' (used
  for > 50% fill)
- arcX: the arc's x position, formulated by Math.cos(2 * Math.PI *
  fillPercent)
- arcY: the arc's y position, formulated by Math.sin(2 * Math.PI *
  fillPercent)

Example:

*myCircularProgressIndicator.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-card class="circularProgress">
        <div class="slds-progress-ring">
            <div class="slds-progress-ring__progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="88">
                <svg viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
                    <path class="slds-progress-ring__path" id="slds-progress-ring-path-41" d={svgURL}></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-progress-ring__content">{percent}</div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

*myCircularProgressIndicator.js*

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CircularProgressIndicator extends LightningElement {
    @api percent;
    @api size;
    fillpercent;
    isLong = 1;
    arcX = 0;
    arcY = 0;
    svgURL = "";

    connectedCallback() {
        this.fillpercent = eval(this.percent);
        this.isLong = (this.fillpercent > 0.5) ? 1 : 0;
        this.arcX = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * this.fillpercent);
        this.arcY = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * this.fillpercent);
        this.svgURL = `M 1 0 A 1 1 0 ${this.isLong} 1 ${this.arcX} ${this.arcY} L 0 0`;
    }
}
```

*myCircularProgressIndicator.css*

```
.circularProgress{
    --lwc-squareIconUtilityLarge: 5rem;
    --lwc-progressRingWidth:0.7rem;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundSuccessDark:gray;
}
```

*This can be used inside other component as below.*

```
<template>
    <c-my-circular-progress-indicator percent="4/5" ></c-my-circular-progress-indicator>
</template>
```

*How it Looks*

[image]